# how to get full path in controller for image in assest folder rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @page_title = 'Blog'
    set_meta_tags og: {
                      title: 'Blog ',
                      image: ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(my_path)
                      }
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    render layout: "layouts/blog"
  end
end
```

i am using "meta tag" gem and wanted to pass different image on pages. my problem is i can get image but i lost Base url. how can i solve that?

Comment: try ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url(my_path)

Comment: @SachinR its in my code above . its not working though. :(

Comment: No, you have `asset_path` instead of `asset_url`